# Call phtml using block code

Tags: phtml, magento2.4.2, cms-block, cms-pages

login to magento admin. Open any cms page and write block code in content section.

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"}}
After using the block code phtml file will be called on cms page but after Footer.

How can we call before footer

Comment: Can you let me know how you added the block to the cms page?
Usually, it will be before the footer.
You know you can edit the content in the admin.
I mean, it's ordered like this Header, Content, and Footer.

Comment: I added phtml file then i created new cms page and added below code

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"}} 
https://prnt.sc/RRuD32GqgXJP

Comment: Ok, And it is added after the footer block?

Comment: no
https://prnt.sc/zrmq5zhQSr2A

Comment: You don't understand.
Is it added after the footer block?

Comment: @WangGang use Widget instead calling it from CMS Page and set location Before footer,And select page

Comment: Not added after the block

Comment: I tried both ways but showing after footer @Ketan borada

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding the widget.

1. Add widget
2. Select Type (CMS Static Block)
3. Select Theme (Your Theme)
4. Widget Title
5. Assign to Store View
6. Click on Add Layout Update
7. Display on All Pages
8. Select Before Page footer from Container
9. Change the section to Widget Options
10. Select the Static Block
11. Click on Save.

Clear the cache and navigate your browser to view.

[image]

Now you can view your block before the page footer.